# Calculate probability in a dataset

Tags: probability

What is a good way to calculate probabilities in a dataset of samples? Each sample is a measurement, that is usually 1 or 0. The goal is to calculate probabilities based on all feature rows.

Simple example dataset:

```
    feature   label
    dog       1
    dog       0
    dog       0
    dog       0
    cat       1
    cat       0
```

Expected Output:

```
    feature  result
    dog      0.25
    cat      0.5
```

The real dataset has around 50 features.

Comment: For your `dog` label, would you expect `0.75` or `0.25`?

Comment: Thanks, 0.25 is correct!

Comment: See my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you've could simply calculate the mean for each feature, however I am not sure if that is exactly what you want. If you have already loaded your data into a pandas dataframe this would be as simple as

```py
df.groupby(["feature"]).mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that *X* are features and *y* - labels

```
#Put algorithm as you wish 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train )


clf.predict_proba(X_test) # there you will get probabilities of the class
```